# Visual Studio 2013 Test - Test explorer - Debug Selected Test: is possible to view the output in real time

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

If I run a test in debug mode is possible to view the output in real time and not just at the end of the test?
I've a compiled library that print out some debug infos (NHibernate show_sql to be more precise) and I like to see it during debug.